# Why does LTspice have a hard time to simulate this?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

update : when the two-transistor structure is replaced by a darlington model provided as spice model by the manufacturer, the gain dependence of stable waveforms disappeared. Now, without those gain setting resistors, everything is fine.

[image]

If the circuit is like that, when the opAmp is connected to out node with R13 and R14 gain mechanism, everything is fine. It simulates easily and plots nice waveforms.

However when I decrease the gain, by deleting all gain mechanism(making direct connection to out node from inverting input) or by just setting R13 to 1k(to lower gain again); it really stucks while simulating(transient). The simulation speed is comperably slower than the first case and also the drawings of waveforms related are like these:

[image]

or a close lookup

[image]

So, it is not about the values of resistors because I have tried with 82 and 10 and it was nice. It is about the ratio of R13 to R14, which is the gain simply if I am not wrong.

Vcc is 7 volts and the signal at the non-inverting input is a sinusoidal wave 1Vpp at 1kHz.

Comment: Your amplifier is oscillating (LTspice slows its time-step to capture the detail). Adding extra gain to an opamp in a fed-back loop often invokes dreaded oscillations.

Comment: And changing the feedback to *decrease* the closed-loop gain is what is *increasing* the open-loop gain and causing the problem. You need to compensate for the frequency response of the transistorized output section; an appropriately-sized cap from the opamp output to its inverting input *may* do the trick, but you'll have to experiment, and it'll reduce your amplifier bandwidth.

Comment: @glen_geek hmm, is the reason for that something you can explain in detail in an answer?

Comment: @TimWescott how can I know the appropriate sized cap value? Input frequency is 1kHz roughly.

Comment: Loop stability is a big subject and a different topic than LTSpice speed: do some reading first. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/negative-feedback-part-4-introduction-to-stability/

Comment: It's a separate question; you should ask it as such.  As pointed out, it's a big subject (book length, to treat it correctly), and because your output stage has considerable zero-crossing distortion the subject gets even bigger.

Comment: Sometimes LTSpice bennefits from added stray capacitance directives: `.options cshunt=1e-15` => Capacitance added from each node to ground. Adding a small CSHUNT to each node can solve some "internal timestep too small" problems caused by high-frequency oscillations or numerical noise. Default = 0. -- This will slow the sim down, but may solve your oscillation issues.

Comment: @Aaron so lets assume the problem with ltspice solved, what will be the real response of the circuit? Will there be those oscillations?

Comment: @muyustan Don't know.  I didn't analyze your circuit. But in real life there is likely to be at least \$0.001pF\$ on each node.

Comment: There's not a problem with LTSpice.  The circuit is oscillating, and LTSpice has to work harder to simulate that - that's why the simulation runs longer.  Nothing wrong with LTSpice.  The circuit is the whole problem.

Comment: @JRE what should I look into to solve the problem?

Comment: Some of the other comments made suggestions.  Look into them.  I'm a hobbyist who does things by the seat of his pants.  I can recognize the problem when I see it (in your scope pictures,) but I don't know the proper ways of designing a solution.  One alternative might be to use a different opamp - the 741 is not the best opamp around.

Comment: @muyustan...you can try to externally compensate the opamp by inserting a suitable resistor (or even better: A series resistor-capacitor combination)  between both opamp input nodes. Thereby you are reducing the loop gain....